# OCCI with C++ error: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I have created a simple C++ programm to connect the Oracle OCCI with a OracleDB instance.

Here is the Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <occi.h>

//  Connection information
const std::string userName = "admin";
const std::string password = "password";

const std::string connectString = "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.8.190)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB)))";                    

//  Connection enviroment
oracle::occi::Environment *env = oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment();


int main() {

int succes;

oracle::occi::Connection *conn = env->createConnection(userName, password, connectString);
succes = 0;

std::string id;
std::cin >> id;

std::string anw = "SELECT * FROM BESTAND WHERE ID=";

std::string cnw = anw + id;

oracle::occi::Statement *stmt = conn -> createStatement(cnw);

oracle::occi::ResultSet *rs = stmt -> executeQuery();

while (rs -> next()) {

std::string b = rs -> getString(2);

std::cout << b << std::endl;

}



stmt -> closeResultSet(rs);
conn -> terminateStatement(stmt);
env -> terminateConnection(conn);

oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

}
```

I use g++ on CentOS-8 to complie the programm, and the programm compilies without a problem but when i execute the Programm i get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'oracle::occi::SQLException'
what():  ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

Have anybody here an idea how i can fix this problem.

Comment: Leave out spaces in the connect string

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: The connect string is correct. You should have a look at the environment. Is ORACLE_HOME set ?

Comment: how i configure this variable on the connect client?

Comment: @Skoti23 Are you on Windows or Linux.Database installed on your laptop/desktop or connecting to instance on remote server?.If you're connecting to remote database did you install Oracle instant client.Most probably your environment was not set propetly as Brandt suspected

Comment: @Sam Im on CentOS-8 Linux with the C++ programm, and the Database is on a Linux Server in my local network.

Comment: You can set environment with this command `. oraenv`(there is a dot and space before oraenv) or add environment variables to your bash profile or to a file and source it here is an example for [environment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/rilin/setting-the-oracle-user-environment-variables.html#GUID-B2A2E0E2-DD9B-4536-9228-CC38EE27AAF3) variables

Answer (score 0):

Is "ORCLCDB" the SERVICE_NAME, or the ORACLE_SID? Service names are usually fully qualified with a domain. You can try this (spaces are fine):

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.8.190)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = ORCLCDB)))
```

Or double-check the service name from the TNS Listener status to make sure you've got the right value. The "lsnrctl status" command on the database server should return a list of active services; use one with a status of "READY".

Comment: ORCLCD is the SID but i get still still the same error even after i tried out your version of the connection string. btw I can connect to the database via a sql-ide so the informations of the connection string must be correct.